# Mean Imputation with SQL

Tags: sql, sas

```
PROC SQL;

    UPDATE GUEST 
    SET 
    STAY_DURATION = ( CASE WHEN STAY_DURATION EQ . THEN MEAN(STAY_DURATION ) 
    ELSE STAY_DURATION END AS STAY_DURATION FORMAT 8.0 END); 

RUN;
```

I would like to insert the average straight into the dataset without going through the process of creating a new table then update the main dataset. Well, I did this but I want to use a nested CASE statement with the update query for multiple variables.

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with just re-writing the dataset? (or making a new one)

Comment: It's a small project that I am doing, thing is part of the criteria involves data cleansing, thus my first gravitation towards mean imputation for numeric and mode for categorical. I am not sure what is meant by re-writing the dataset, kindly explain? I know mean imputation introduces SD variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery for the calculation:

```
PROC SQL;    
    UPDATE GUEST 
        SET STAY_DURATION = (SELECT AVG(STAY_DURATION) FROM GUEST)
        WHERE STAY_DURATION IS NULL;
```

If you want to just use `PROC SQL`, you can use two steps:

```
PROC SQL;   
    CREATE TABLE AVG_GUEST AS 
        SELECT AVG(STAY_DURATION) as AVG_SD FROM GUEST;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
    UPDATE GUEST 
        SET STAY_DURATION = (SELECT AVG_SD FROM AVG_GUEST)
        WHERE STAY_DURATION IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Though it is giving me an error: WARNING: A value expression of the SET clause references the data set being updated.
 ERROR: You cannot reopen GUEST.DATA for update access with member-level control because GUEST.DATA 
 is in use by you in resource environment SQL (2).

Comment: Do it in two steps.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. That is the code I have currently working but what to do is some like what is below PROC SQL;
 
 CREATE TABLE GUEST AS SELECT
 
 CASE WHEN STAY_DURATION EQ . THEN MEAN(STAY_DURATION) ELSE 
           STAY_DURATION END AS AVG_STAY_DURATION FORMAT 5.0,
 
    CASE WHEN ROOM_COST EQ . THEN MEAN(ROOM_COST) ELSE 
              ROOM_COST END AS AVG_ROOM_COST FORMAT 5.0,
   
    CASE WHEN BONUS EQ . THEN MEAN(BONUS) ELSE 
              BONUS END AS AVG_BONUS FORMAT 5.0 
              FROM AFT_TRAIN;

Comment: PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE X AS SELECT
CASE WHEN VAR EQ . THEN AVG(VAR) ELSE VAR END AS AVG_VAR FORMAT 5.0,
CASE WHEN VAR_B EQ . THEN AVG(VAR_B) ELSE VAR_B END AS AVG_VAR_B FORMAT 5.0,
....
FROM TABLE;

Note: this is working but I have no primary key to join this small table to the main one.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally not a good idea to overwrite your input data.  Make a new dataset with your modifications to the data.  You can use PROC STDIZE to replace missing values with the mean of the variable.

```
proc stdize data=guest out=want reponly missing=mean;
  var stay_duration;
run;
```

In SQL

```
proc sql;
  create table WANT as 
    select *
         , coalesce(stay_duration,mean(stay_duration)) as stay_duration_imputed
    from guest
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will do PROC STDIZE  on a copy train set for a start.  Already done logistic regression with mean imputation, AUC 78% only. One caveat is that SQL must be used in pre-processing. Nonetheless I'll standardize a copy dataset first then try LR modeling again...hope it sorts out any outlier issues too.  Cheers!

Comment: That worked too! I will make different SQLs to do the same thing just to spicy things up. Cheers!